# Python Unittest for method returning json string

Tags: python, python-unittest

I ma new to writing python unit tests. I have a method in a class returning a Json response from an API. The JSON response contains attributes such as data, token, object name and status. The method hits API and returns response with different values each time, so I can't hard code a response and test it. How can I write a unit test for this type of method.

One thing, I thought of is to check whether the response is not null. Is there any other type of checks I can do here.

Each time it returns a different token, date(timestamp). The status will be same.

```
def Json_get_status(self):
    get_url = "xxxx" #URL to hit API
    r = requests.get(get_url)
    self.get_json = json.loads(r.text)
    self.get_token=self.get_json["token"]
    self.get_date=self.get_json["date"]
    self.get_status=self.get_json["status"]
    return self.get_json
```

Comment: Will *all* of the data be different each time, or are there some fields you can test for? Could you test that all fields are of the correct type, or in appropriate ranges? Could you mock out the API call? What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Just a made a edit in question. Yes, I can try to mock API call. I am trying to test whether this method reads the status correctly from the Json response.

Comment: You might find this easier if you split it into more separate parts - testing whether a method can correctly parse a JSON string should be trivial. Could you post the method, with a minimal class skeleton around it?

Comment: added method skeleton

Answer (score 0):

If your method under test is supposed to "read the status correctly", then you might want to specifically test that.

So assuming your app is something like

```
def read_status(response):
    parsed = json.loads(response)
    # does other stuff
    return something
```

Then in your test_unit.py

```
def test_read_status(self):
   mock_input_val = {'something': 'good val'}
   expected_positive_return_val = something
   self.assertEqual(read_status(json.dumps(mock_input_val)),       
                    expected_positive_return_val)
```

Also good to do a negative test for the condition where read_status either fails to parse the json object or finds an error in the response.

Comment: Yeah, but its not receiving json as arguement. it polls API everytime and then uses that JSON response(internal to method)

Comment: Based on the code you provided, I would suggest making an internal function that receives the output of json.loads(resp.text), then unit test that function. That way your are decoupling the network and business logic. There's not much value in unit testing something that simply issues an http get. You can get more complex with mock services, but starting simple is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests_mock` to mock responses

```
import requests_mock
...


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @requests_mock.Mocker()
    def test_json_get_status(self, mocker):
        mocker.get("http://xxxx", text='{"token": "mock", "date": "mock", "status": "mock"}')
        self.assertIsNotNone(YourClass().json_get_status())
```